# How to display the value of a field of a related table, and not its code using a LINQ-query, C#, SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have created several related tables. For the link, I'm using a field code from another table. When I try to display a table through a LINQ query, it does not display the field value, but its code. How to display the value?

The program uses C#, SQL Server, LINQ. The database was created in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

The data is retrieved using a similar query.

```
var objDataContext = new LinqDBDataContext(); // Получаем таблицы

Console.WriteLine("Таблица: Объект недвижимости");
var queryProterty = from c in objDataContext.Property
                                    select c;
foreach (var c in queryProterty)
{  
    Console.WriteLine(c.district);
}
```

[image: output example]

[image: table links]

Comment: The resolution on your images is too small (for me to read).  Can you replace with higher resolution images?

Comment: Would you please share the code for your Property and District entities ?